# How to update a notification without notifying in Android?

Tags: android, notifications, updates

So I have an app that receives the temperature via MQTT. To avoid getting spammed by notifcations, I want the app to notify once, that is vibrate, play sound and then the next three times (if the notification isn't dismissed) it will only update the temperature value. So:

1. Notify
2. Update temp
3. Update temp
4. Update temp
   5(or 1 if you will) Notify

This is my code:

```
 private final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);

 private void handleNotification(String message, String topic) {
        if (notifManager == null) {
            notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }

        if (isNotifRunning() && ticker < 3) {
            updateNotif(message);
            ticker++;
        } else {
            createNotif(message);
            ticker = 0;
        }
    }

    private void createNotif(String message) {

        Intent intent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200});
                notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            }
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notifTmpLowTitle))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ac_unit_black_24px)
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.notifTmpLowText) + " " + message + Constants.CELSIUS)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker(message)
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCold))
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200});

        } else {

            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notifTmpLowTitle))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_ac_unit_black_24px)
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.notifTmpLowText) + " " + message + Constants.CELSIUS)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setTicker(message)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200})
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorCold))
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        }
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }

    //TODO Doesn't update, posts a new notification.
    private void updateNotif(String message) {
        builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.notifTmpLowText) + " " + message + Constants.CELSIUS);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
```

With this code, I always get, what it looks like, a brand new notification with sound and vibration. I've looked at previous questions regarding this and they all say that it's important to use the same builder and as you can see, I have done this. Is there some change in newer Android versions that I'm not aware of? I've tested on both 7.1.1 and 8.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to call [setOnlyAlertOnce(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOnlyAlertOnce(boolean)) to cause updates to your notification to not send sound/vibration.

Comment: Great, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Just a weird issue though. Now the time of when the notification was fired never changes. Not even if I cancel it and create a new one, the time just increases. Right now it is up in 19 hours. I'm talking about the time property you can enable or disable by using  builder.setShowWhen(bool);

Comment: If you're reusing the same builder, you should be calling [setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setWhen(long)) if you want to update the time (it defaults to when the Builder was first created).